# I need to reference a cell based on drop-down values from four different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've searched and tried it all but I'm finally admitting to being stuck. I need to reference a cell based on drop-down values from four different columns.

Essentially I am trying to compile a summary list of data from different tabs. Each tab is laid out the same however on this new summary I need to pull the data from A2 based on a value in D2:G2. I have tried so many different formulas to no avail. I've come closest with:

=INDEX(Assessments!D2:G2,MATCH(TRUE,A1,Assessments!A2),0)

This return the #VALUE message stating that parameter 3 expects number values but "NAME" is a text and cannot be coerced into a number.

and

=vlookup($A$1,{Assessments!D2:G2,Assessments!A2},1,0)

This returns the value in A1 however, I actually need it to return the text from Assessments!A2

Data sets:

| Name | Launch | Description | Tag | Tag | Tag | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assement Title A | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Assement Title B | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title C | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Assement Title D | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace |  |  |  |
| Assement Title E | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Assement Title F | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Assement Title G | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title H | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Assement Title I | rd_28 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace |  |  |
| Assement Title J | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |
| Assement Title K | rd_28 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Assement Title L | rd_28 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |

This information would ideally be pulled into a new sheet with the following column headers: (A1 = Enhance)

| Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Once I have all the assessment data in a linear format, I'd need to use the formula again to pull data from the other tabs, such as:

| Name | Launch | Description | Tag | Tag | Tag | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doc Title A | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace |  |  |
| Doc Title B | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Doc Title C | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace |  |
| Doc Title D | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Doc Title E | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate | Enhance |  |
| Doc Title F | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |  |
| Doc Title G | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Embrace |  |  |
| Doc Title H | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance | Enlighten | Embrace | Educate |
| Doc Title I | rd_1 | Testing | Enlighten | Embrace | Enhance |  |
| Doc Title J | rd_1 | Testing | Educate |  |  |  |
| Doc Title K | rd_1 | Testing | Embrace | Educate |  |  |
| Doc Title L | rd_1 | Testing | Enhance |  |  |  |

Comment: "I can't share my sheet for privacy reasons" so make up a sheet with mock data

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, {Assessments!D2, Assessments!A2}, 2, 0)
```